# Set callback onBlur on select element

Tags: javascript, html

I am aware that the select HTML element has an `onChange` and `onFocus` event listener, but is there a way to call a function when the user clicks out of the select menu without selecting an option?

Comment: is [onfocusout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocusout.asp) any help for you?

Comment: `Tip: Although Firefox does not support the onfocusout event, you can find out whether a child of an element loses focus or not, by using a capturing listener for the onblur event (using the optional useCapture parameter of the addEventListener() method).`

Comment: Due to the fact that browser **does not** send the click nor other mouse events when you click outside the native select element when it's open (at least not on MacBook Chrome), you're stuck unless someone knows a way around that.

Comment: If this is an important feature for you, I'd make my own dropdown but don't forget the focus management and aria stuff. Might be too tricky for beginner though.

Comment: @shukar select does not lose the focus when you click outside, even if the click target is focusable, e.g button. At least on MacBook Chrome, not sure about others.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use the "on click outside" technique.

https://github.com/BosNaufal/click-outside-js
https://github.com/TooTallNate/click-outside

Instead of looking for `onBlur` event you detect that user clicked outside your HTML element. It should be enough to implement the logic you want.

When `onFocus` is called you set some flag, like `selectOpen` to `true`. Then `onClickOutside` event you check is the flag set for `true` and call any code you want.

Comment: I have tried that approach but it doesn't seem to work. When I "first" click outside the `select`, the dropdown closes but doesn't fire the `onClickOutside` event. It's only when I click outside a second time, that's when the event fires.

I was wondering if it has anything to do with when the `select` is opened, the entire page is not scrollable so we are technically clicking inside the `select` element? Like on this page, https://fafruch.github.io/react-rrule-generator/ when you open a `select`, the page is not scrollable when `select` is focused.